# 415 Unsupported Media Type jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, rest, spring-mvc

I am using the Maven Rest API. I'm getting a 415 error when I make a POST request through a jQuery Ajax call. Please have a look on my code.

```js
function getUserDetails() {
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var mobile = $("#mobile").val();
  var location = $("#location").val();
  var email = $("#email").val();

  var userDetails = {
    "name": name,
    "mobile": mobile,
    "email": email,
    "location": location
  };

  return userDetails;
}

function createuser() {
  sendRequest("registerProcess", getUserDetails(), "post");
}

function sendRequest(url, input, method) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    async: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(input),
    error: function(response) {
      //displayResponseMessage(response);
      console.log("Error");
    },
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(" Successfull");
    },
    type: method,
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
      contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    },
    dataType: 'json'
  });
}
```

This is my controller. The `UserForm` is a POJO Class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registerProcess", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String addUser(@RequestBody UserForm user) 
{  
  System.out.println("Inside Controller" );
  String email = user.getEmail();
  String mobile = user.getMobile();
  System.out.println("Details :" + email + mobile);
  return "welcome";
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415

Comment: Aside from the immediate problem, but *never, ever use `async: false`*. There is no reason to use this if you are using the callback pattern correctly.

Comment: As for the issue itself, a 415 error indicates the request is not in the correct format. You're sending JSON - are you sure the API is expecting that, and not form-urlencoded data?

Comment: Try `data:input` instead of `data: JSON.stringify(input)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the header as `'Content-Type' : 'application/json'` and here input is an object which can be sent directly in ajax request `data :input`

Comment: It works by editing data: input and 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'. Removed async: false.Thank you for ur replies.