# Can't pass/receive values with POST request AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, post

I'm trying to send some data with an Ajax Post request.
The code of the request is the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "[url of page]",
    type: "POST",
    data: {saluto: true},
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function (response) {
        alert("successful" + response);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

So in this case I should receive `saluto = true`

This is the Backend code:

```
[HttpPost("Test")]
public async Task<string> testHelloWorld(bool saluto)
{

    try
    {
        string testString = "Funziona";
        Console.Write(testString + ": " + saluto + "\n");
        return testString;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error("API(CallToXML) - Exception", ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

So if `saluto = true`
My console should print `"Funziona: True"`
the OUTPUT tho is `"Funziona: False"`

If I try the same thing with a string, it won't print the string and just leaves the output like `"Funziona: "`

Why isn't my code reciving any data?
Is there anything I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: please include the code used to send and receive the string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bool parameter from jQuery Ajax received as literal string "false"/"true" in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408976/bool-parameter-from-jquery-ajax-received-as-literal-string-false-true-in-php)

Comment: No but it does look like javascript, which is where the issue lies.

Comment: @TommasoBertoni It's the same code, I just change the ```bool saluto``` to ```string saluto``` and the frontend request becames ```saluto:"prova"```

Comment: do you receive `saluto == false` when you send `true` from the frontend?

Comment: @TommasoBertoni Yes, I typed that at the end of the question

Comment: @peeebeee If you read my js it is different from the one in your question so this is not the case. Anyway that didn t fix the problem. Thanks anyway for the help

Comment: does it work if you send the request in `GET` instead of `POST`?

Comment: @TommasoBertoni yes

Comment: can you try to just send the value? using `data: true` or `data: "true"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196580/discussion-between-tommaso-bertoni-and-synapsis).

Comment: I can't because I won't read that as the parameter my function asks for.
The output will just be "Funziona:  " leaving a blank space for the variable

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `"data: "` and changing `"url: "` to: `{ value: "~/Controller/Method?saluto=true" })`.

Comment: I tryed your method and it works but if I try to send a bigger string it won't work. The status of the request will still return an error

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the signature of your action to

```
public async Task<string> testHelloWorld([FromBody]bool saluto)
```

By default the model binder looks for simple types in the request parameters not the body of the request.

Take a look [Tadej's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41027149/592958) to [Why do we have to specify FromBody and FromUri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625303/why-do-we-have-to-specify-frombody-and-fromuri) for more information.

Comment: The data is simple and sent using `POST`, therefore it can't be extracted `FromUri`

Comment: @TommasoBertoni quite correct, should have been `[FromBody]` - corrected

Comment: That's better, but I don't think that will fix it. asp.net should be able to understand the source if there is only one parameter or if the request comes by `POST`

Comment: I'm currently checking if another answer works. I'll check this method in a sec, thanks

Comment: @phuzi Adding only the [FromBody] didn't help, it actually made it worse cause the request couldn't even be sent

Comment: @Synapsis with the `FromBody` did you get an http error response?

Comment: Try setting `content: 'application/json'` on the request

Comment: @Synapsis sounds like a different problem. Try adding
 `headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
}` see here for info -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988605/415-unsupported-media-type-jquery-ajax

Comment: @phuzi still not working, I don't think that the data is the issue here